# Do search engines consider the length of longer percent-encoded URLs or shorter non-English character URLs for SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, url-encoding

Do search engines consider the length of non-English characters or do they consider the length of percentage-encoded characters for an SEO score?

For example:

```
http://example.com/%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%b3%d9%8a%d8%a7-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b9%d9%85%d9%84-%d8%b9%d9%84%d9%89-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%aa
```

I searched here and found related posts are 3 to 7 years old. Is there any update in how popular search engines index URLs with non-English characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every URL parser should be using [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) as the official definition of the URL format and should follow the **rules on how to encode and decode URL**. That guarantees to work properly with the rest of the Internet.

Search Engines [normalize URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization) mainly to **reduce crawling and indexing of duplicate** pages, so, in the end, the length they will use is associated to the normalized URL.

As they have stated in [their official guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en), we should always work with encoded UTF-8 URLs :

> However, be sure to use UTF-8 encoding in the URL (in fact, we recommend using UTF-8 wherever possible) and remember to escape the URLs properly when linking to them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you pl confirm what should I do if my URL after percentage-encoding is 171 characters long. (As per SEO it be about 50 to 60 characters)

Comment: You don't need to do anything, for searchers that URL will be 50/60 characters long as they will normalize it. That's what really matters. However, you can use Google Search Console > Inspect URL to check how Google is working with your URL and confirm everything is correct https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en